# Index match returning N/A when lookup value is null

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a summary sheet in a workbook that allows a user to enter in a 3 digit ID and some summary data and a chart populates. In the source data, the ID for the totals row is blank. So, when the lookup value is blank (no 3 digit ID is entered) I expected the Index Match formula to return the values corresponding to a blank cell in the lookup array, but it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Sampling of the data:

```
 ID   March    April
111   10         15
222   15         10
333   10         10
      35         35
```

Formula used:

```
=INDEX(B9:B12,MATCH(A1,A9:A12,0))
```

Where A1 is the lookup value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to enter the name in **A1** and retrieve the age in **B1** and also accommodate the blank in column **E**.

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="",INDEX(F:F,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(E1:E30),0,0),0)),VLOOKUP(A1,E2:F21,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lookup a blank cell. Use  IFERROR to find the first blank with AGGREGATE in the target if you receive an #N/A.

```
=INDEX(B9:B12, iferror(MATCH(A1,A9:A12,0), aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$4)/not(len(A9:A12)), 1)))
```

row($1:$4) is the **position within** B9:B12 that you are returning to the INDEX.

Comment: So, to scale this up, would I use row($1:$5000) if my data is in B3:B5002?

Comment: Yes, you are looking for the *position within* B3:B5002. Just as your original MATCH was returning a number between 1 and 4 from A9:A12 to get the position within B9:B12, you can scale this up to 1:5000 within B3:B5002.